# How to return JSON object to AngularJS using Java Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, servlets

I have to write a controller in my project using servlets. I've done it before but I've never worked with AngularJS, so I did it via `request.setAttribute()` and `request.getParameter()` and put Java code inside of a JSP page. But now frontend developer used AngularJS and I have to return him a JSON object. And I have no idea how to do it. Here's the code of `abTestCtrl.js`:

```
app.controller("abTestCtrl", function($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.title = "no title";
        $scope.description = "no description";
    $scope.getParam = $location.search()['id'];
    if($scope.getParam === undefined)$scope.getParam = 0; 

    //$scope.getParam=2;
    //path: localhost8080/UIUM.../servlet-name.java
        //with two ids
        //web.xml: serverlet mapping for the path
        if($scope.getParam==='0'||$scope.getParam === 0){
            var saveButton = document.getElementById("saveButton");
            saveButton.classList.remove("hidden");
        }
        else{
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/UIUM_IMT4003/ABTestController', {command:'getTestCaseInfo', testcaseID:$scope.getParam}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // this callback will be called asynchronously
              // when the response is available
              console.log('request succesful');
              console.log(data);
              console.log(status);
              console.log(headers);
              console.log(config);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // called asynchronously if an error occurs
              // or server returns response with an error status.
              console.log('request not succesful');
            });
        }
```

and my `processRequest()` code from the servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        //PrintWriter printout = response.getWriter();

        JSONObject jObject = null;
        RequestDispatcher view = null;
        TestcaseRepository testcaseRepo = new TestcaseRepository();

        String command = request.getParameter("command");

        if(command == null)
        {
            view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/testcases.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        }

        if(command.equals("getTestCaseInfo")){
            String testcaseId = request.getParameter("testcaseID");
            Testcase testcase = testcaseRepo.getTestcaseById(testcaseId);
            jObject = new JSONObject();
            jObject.put("id", testcaseId);
            jObject.put("title", testcase.getTestcaseName());
            jObject.put("testscenario", testcase.getTestcaseDescription());
//            printout.print(jObject);
//            printout.flush();
            jObject.write(response.getWriter());
        }
```

Can you please help me to process this request and finally return this poor JSON!

BTW, Servlet doesn't recognize `command` parameter. It gets `null`. But there is such parameter in AngularJS function.

Comment: Help with what? You're just dumping some code without saying what's wrong.

Comment: If you are getting error, post the error messages/stack traces detailing what was expected and what is happening. BTW, I would have used JSON converter If I were you.

Comment: @Gimby cite: "But now frontend developer used AngularJS and I have to return him a JSON object. And I have no idea how to do it." It's seems obviously for me, that I can't return JSON object to AngularJS.

Comment: @mityakoval `request.getparameter()` is always returning null for me also. How did you fix it?

Comment: @kittu the problem was in AngularJS code. You should send the parameters clearly. For example, instead of `$http.get('http://localhost:8080/UIUM_IMT4003/ABTestController', {command:'getTestCaseInfo', testcaseID:$scope.getParam})` you should write `http://localhost:8080/UIUM_IMT4003/ABTestController?command=getTestCaseInfo&testcaseID='+$scope.getParam+''`. As soon as I did that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `javax.json.JsonObject` as follow:

```
JsonObject jo=Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", testcaseId)
            .add("title", testcase.getTestcaseName())
            .add("testscenario", testcase.getTestcaseDescription()).build();
```

Then set the response content type to json and send your json object in the response:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");// set content to json
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(jo);
out.flush();
```